# Keeping sorted sequence without a less-than predicate

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I want to keep a sorted queue of items, where I want to be able to pop the item with the lowest value (a bit like `std::priority_queue`). The item values are contiguous and ever increasing. However, the items do not have less-than comparison defined, they only have `is-previous` and `is-next` predicates (where `A is-previous B` == `B is-next A`), they also support `++` or `--`.

I wonder if there is any algorithm to (partially) sort values, based on such predicates? Alternately, is there a better way to keep track of such a queue?

This problem occurs when working in modulo arithmetic - the items are designated by integers, but thanks to the modulo, less than and greater than lose their meaning, and cannot be used for sorting anymore.

The language of choice is C++, but I guess I can port most of the reasonable languages.

**EDIT**

Appologies to all the people trying to answer, while writing the example code, I realized the original question was ill-formed. It is really embarasing, but I would like to emphasize that your time was not wasted, as I was sweating over it for one hour, and then in 10 minutes I realized how it is wrong. Anyway, this is the behavior I want:

```
template <class T>
class OrderedQueue {
    std::vector<T> storage;
    T next;

public:
    OrderedQueue(T lowest_value = T())
        :next(lowest_value)
    {}

    void Push(T t)
    {
        storage.push_back(t);
    }

    T Pop()
    {
        std::vector<T>::iterator it = std::find(storage.begin(), storage.end(), next);
        if(it == storage.end())
            throw std::runtime_error("no such element");
        T value = *it;
        storage.erase(it);
        ++ next;
        return value;
    }
};
```

My problem is that `Pop()` takes `O(N)`. Is there a way to make it faster, using the is-prev and is-next predicates?

Comment: Why do you need to sort them? You can't add anything in the middle!

Comment: @Basilevs I would like to sort them, as keeping a sorted array is usually much faster than unsorted one. I would not be able to use `std::priority_queue` anyway, since it requires a less than predicate. I would use `std::vector` to store the values, and there you can easily `vector.insert(where, 1, what)`.

Comment: Wrap deque, and disallow any insertions except for start and end.

Comment: @Basilevs That's not really helpful. What if the item with the lowest value ends up in the middle? I will never get to it.

Comment: ((a _is-previous_ b) iff (b _is-next_ a)?) Looks like a topsort knowing the vertexes, but not the edges (from the start). I see no way to sort the items non-ambiguously if there is more than one without a predecessor, making pop ill-defined. Will additions/insertions of items need to be supported?

Comment: It can't by construction turn out to be at the middle - we only allow proper entries to  be inserted at the begin or the end of sequence.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, `(a is-previous b) iff (b is-next a)` holds. Insertion of an item which is bounded by a maximum distance from the current minimum needs to be supported, removal of an item with the lowest value needs to be supported.

Comment: @Basilevs hmm. that's interesting. But what about the "improper" entries? Can't just throw them away ...

Comment: Do you want to keep existing collection or to sort initially unordered dump?

Comment: Can items be omitted or duplicated?

Comment: Won't forest of "valid " sequences do?

Comment: @Basilevs yes, a forest of sorted sequences would indeed work. It also neatly captures the ambiguity in the original question. Now I only need to figure out how to do the memory management to avoid reallocations, if the size of the queue is known.

Comment: Example's Pop code is severely broken. Please, review.

Comment: Returns type. Increments value. Forgets erased value.

Comment: If you're writing a library to uphold one end of a contract, then tell us the contract. Otherwise, tell us the concrete instance of the actual problem and stop trying to generalize prematurely, because it's a waste of time to read through broken formalisms that you don't actually care about.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I am actually writing this kind of queue. It is also thread-safe, and failure in `Pop()` is supposed to cause the calling thread to sleep, but that is another problem entirely. The code, as is, does what I want. Honest :).

Comment: Depending on the modulo math, if every number except zero can be treated as a power of some primitive for that field, then the "logarithm" of every number in that field could be used to define a less than or greater than, with zero being the "smallest" number with a logarithm of -1 for convenience, using signed integers for the logarithms. If the field is modulo some prime number there is a primitive for that field. Is there a reason that pop and push operations would be faster if the numbers are "sorted"?

Comment: Will, you fix the code? You are still incrementing next member, which is not an iterator. And you never return it.

Comment: @Basilevs But that is correct! The `next` member shows which item should be returned next. The items are contiguous, and without the less-than operator, there could be, at any time, more than one candidate for the lowest value item (as in the sequence forest you proposed). The value of `next` resolves this ambiguity.

Comment: I still think, iterator should be incremented. not value.

Comment: @Basilevs Well, it works. I can post my complete evaluation code if you want.

Comment: Yes, it might be a good idea to prove you point on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com)

Comment: @Basilevs here http://ideone.com/lZE4IE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61625/discussion-between-basilevs-and-the-swine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that Pop() takes O(N). Is there a way to make it faster, using the is-prev and is-next predicates?

You need to provide a way to get to the actual modular integer representation of the key, say `Integer(x)`. Then `Push` and `Pop` can both be performed in constant time.

If you have the integers and the modulus `M`, use an array of doubly-linked lists (`std::list<T> queues[M]`), implement `Push(x)` as `queues[Integer(x)].push_back(x)` and `Pop` as

```
size_t i = Integer(next);
// check for existence, raise if necessary
T r = queues[i].front();
queues[i].pop_front();
return r;
```

If `M` is large and you expect most of the queues to be empty most of the time, then you can use a `std::unordered_map<size_t, std::list<T>>` to get the same complexity but save space.

An `std::deque` can also be used; that provides only amortized constant-time for both operations, but may well be a lot faster in practice.

Comment: Doesn't that always store up to one integer per queue (assuming that they do not repeat, but increase steadily - a worst case sequence for your implementation)? I agree that this would work, but it would be horribly inefficient! What if `M = 2^32`? If I could get the integer representation, I could then use `std::set` or `std::map` and make both `Push()` and `Pop()` logarithmic time.

Comment: @theswine If M is large, use an `unordered_map<size_t, list<T>>` to get constant time push and pop. See updated answer.

Comment: This is really the fastest solution, although not by a large margin. Inserting 100 k of elements to the `OrderedQueue` described in the question is just about 100 msec slower than using `std::unordered_map`. That could improve with a better compiler or a better STL implementation.

Comment: @theswine That's actually not too surprising since the constants in this approach are really, really large. Did you try `std::deque` instead of `std::list`?

Comment: I only implemented it with a single item per bin (assuming no repeated items), but I would expect the `list` to be slightly slower than `deque`.

Comment: Ah. Then it's probably the overhead of hashing that you're seeing. I've noticed suboptimal performance in `unordered_map` implementations before, and I usually evaluate whether a good old `map` is not faster for the problem at hand.

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it is about the same.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ your type does not need to have `operator<` defined to be sorted or to be used in an associative container. The containers and algorithms can take predicates that perform the comparison. For example, to sort a vector using `is_pred` as the predicate (assuming that it is already a function object or a plain function):

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), is_pred);
```

If not, you can write your own functor adapter or a lambda:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
             return apply_is_pred_predicate(lhs,rhs)
          });
```

The requirements here are that the relationship *is-prev* has to be a strict weak order.

Comment: Yes, this won't work, as the predicates described are not a `strict weak ordering`. But thanks.

Comment: Yes, is_previous clearly does not define a strict weak order.